# JBoss 7 admin console stuck at loading

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I just installed Jboss 7.1.1 on my machine. Since some other program is using port 9990, I updated the port to 9995.Then I hit http://:9995/console, the page is stuck at the loading (a spinning loading on the page). This is the log,I didn't find anything really an error. Could anyone tell me how to fix this issue?
Thank you.
This is the log I have.

```
00:20:00,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
00:20:00,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
00:20:00,167 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
00:20:00,167 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
00:20:00,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
00:20:00,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
00:20:00,163 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
00:20:00,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
00:20:00,205 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
00:20:00,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
00:20:00,212 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
00:20:00,272 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
00:20:00,351 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
00:20:00,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory E:\Software\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments
00:20:00,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
00:20:00,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
00:20:00,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
00:20:00,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9995
00:20:00,567 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 1072ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: It looks like a browser issue, if i type 127.0.0.1:9995 instead of localhost:9995 then the login prompts and everything works.  BUT this only works in IE, not in chrome or firefox. I tried to clear the cache of these two browsers, still the login prompt doesnt show up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's probably problem of your OS, not JBoss. You could bind server to all interfaces and it should be working with localhost:9995.

```
standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to setup `localhost` in your `hosts` file. I don't remember where that is on Windows, but it's something like `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.